# Why use MAX232 when using USB-to-Serial cable

Tags: rs232

I was wondering the need to use MAX232 type ICs when using a USB to RS232 converters.
A prolific based converter gives the following output, when transmitting 'a'
[image]

It seems to me that a simple NOT gate will make it suitable to be worked with a micro controller.

```
Note: I think my cable uses a PL-2303HXD USB to Serial Bridge Controller Chip.
```

Comment: The vertical scale is 2v/div. So the voltage stays in the range of 5 to 0v

Comment: Your PL-2303-based cable is *NOT* a USB-to-RS232 adapter. It is using TTL-level voltages (5V or 3.3V), so it is a USB-to-serial adapter. As such, it may be connected to your MCU without anything in between (presuming you're using the same Vcc-level). Actually, putting a MAX232 to your MCU would make it incompatible with this kind of USB-to-serial adapter.

Answer (score 2):

A USB to RS232 cable is supposed to output around -12V for the 1 state and around +12V for the 0 state. Your particular cable might be cutting a few corners. For proper compatibility, you need to use the correct chip. However, if you are building a one-off prototype with a specific cable, then you may be able to get away with hacking something together that does not use the correct interface chips. You may run to unexpected issues, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot does not show the voltage levels. If it is a real USB-to-RS232 converter the low level you see is -5 .. -15V compared to ground. You cannot simply invert that because such negative voltages are outside the allowed input range of a normal inverter (for receiving), and outside of the outout range produced by a normal inverter (for transmitting). The max232 provided a set of inverters that do have this non-standard input and output ranges.

Note that if you just want to receive, the good-old MC1489 offers what you need an no more: a bunch of inverters that can handle negative voltages as inputs. It has a companion for transmission, but that one requires (ao.) a negative power because the negative voltage has to come from somewhere. (A max232 contains a flying-capacitor generator that produces oa. the negative voltage, that's where those extra capacitors are for.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a non-standard usb to serial adapter. Normally in TTL levels (0 and 3.3v) there is no inversion, and in RS232 levels 0 is voltage above 5v and 1 is voltage below -5v. So with that cable indeed you don't need max232 (just an inverter), although it may work. But in your place i would throw away the cable and take something standard.

Comment: *"TTL levels (0 and 3.3v) "*  No, [TTL is 0 and 5 V](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels/ttl-logic-levels)

Comment: Alright, sue me. LVTTL. Or CMOS. There is no real difference anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it you're needing to interface to - something with a true "RS232" interface (i.e. something with a DB9/DB25 connector), or are you connecting to some logic-level circuitry via a male-header on a PCB?

Actual true "RS232" uses both +ve & -ve voltage signalling, but neophytes often use the term "RS232" incorrectly to refer to a logic-level (0V/3.3V or 0V/5V signalling) interface.

Comment: I would be interfacing it with a uC.

Comment: It sounds like you have a cable something like this:  https://www.adafruit.com/products/18 , which is a "USB to RS232" converter, but I think you want a "USB to logic-level-serial" aka "USB to TTL-serial" converter cable, something like: https://www.adafruit.com/products/954 , or if you need the a full(er) set of serial signals (i.e. DTR/DSR &/or CTS/RTS) then something like this: https://www.adafruit.com/products/70 (although note that this one uses the misleading 'RS232' wording!).